# Need to run a database shutdown script before RHEL 7 is rebooted

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel

I am trying to execute the script with systemd and below is the service definition I am using but, the script is not running before the reboot occurs:

```
[Unit]
Description=Before Shutting Down
Before=reboot.target
RequiresMountsFor=/home

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=oracle
ExecStart=/home/oracle/scripts/stop_db.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target
```

Any luck please? Went through multiple solutions suggested without any luck.

Service status:

```
● dbstop.service - Before Shutting Down
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dbstop.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Does the script in the service work if run on its own?

Comment: Yes the script works fine. Even if I start the service using systemctl command then also it works fine and database gets shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start and stop the DB as a service and let systemd do the rest?

```
[Unit]
Description=myDB
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/oracle/scripts/start_db.sh
ExecStop=/home/oracle/scripts/stop_db.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targetYM
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried this as well but, did not work.

Comment: Why didn’t it work?  This is the correct way of doing things.

Comment: ok it did not work